# How can i use a control more than one time in javafx 8?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm currently getting started with javafx 8 and came up with the following problem in a simple solution:

I've different controls (`Button`), which shall appear

1. In the main content (**center** of a `Pane`)
2. In a footer (**bottom** of a `Pane`)

[image: concept]

```
Button one = new Button("1");
Button two = new Button("2");
Button three = new Button("3");

VBox vbox = new VBox();
vbox.getChildren().addAll(one, two, three);

HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.getChildren().addAll(two, three); //To clarify my problem i leave one node in vbox
```

Now it appears to happen that the last `.addAll()`, *deletes* the references in the other box.

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
root.setCenter(vbox);
root.setBottom(hbox);
```

Output:

[image: gui]

I tried (for testing) to simply reuse a button, but:

```
root.setCenter(one);
root.setBottom(one);
```

results in

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = BorderPane@1784a61
```

That made me think about the following questions:

- Is there a way to work around that problem, except creating new button instances?
- *What* happens to the `HBox` and `VBox` nodes?
- *Why* controls can't be reused?

Comment: I don't know why you want to reuse those button controls. For each button you will probably attach some specific events/code when they get clicked. In your case you add Button 2 and 3 once to the vbox and also to the hbox. Hence the error message. I would just declare button 4 and 5 and add those to the hbox. If you used something like scenebuilder, you can't reuse controls there either.

Comment: @WonderWorld you misunderstood my question: The idea of same controls reuse is, that i **want** to have the same control with the same functionality etc. It would really take too long to explain why i do that. **+I dont get any error message with the hbox and vbox approach. the nodes are just gone**

Comment: the nodes are not gone, the last 2 are added to the hbox and not to the vbox because you are using duplicate controls.

Comment: @WonderWorld `gone` in the meaning of _not displayed_

Comment: They are being displayed, but you don't have enough buttons declared to display all 6 of them. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As said in the JavaDocs of the [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) class:

> A node may occur at most once anywhere in the scene graph.
>   Specifically, a node must appear no more than once in all of the
>   following: as the root node of a `Scene`, the children `ObservableList` of
>   a `Parent`, or as the clip of a `Node`.
>
> If a program adds a child node to a `Parent` (including `Group`, `Region`,
>   etc.) and that node is already a child of a different `Parent` or the
>   root of a `Scene`, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from
>   its former parent.

Therefore, you can't do what you're trying to do. One button can only be shown once, you can't have the same button at two places. To make this more clear - what should e.g. the `getParent()` method return if you were able to have the same instance at two places? Nothing, it's impossible. One instance can only exist at one place.

You must copy the button if you want to reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaFX nodes can only be used one time in the scene graph. This makes sence because a node, e.g., contains a location. If you would use it twice you would need two locations.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = BorderPane@1784a6
```

and that the scene shows the `"one" button` in the vbox and `"two"` and `"three"` in the hbox, is related. You declared only 3 buttons and the scene can only show 3 buttons. As per my comment, you need to declare button four and five and add those to the hbox and probably you will get to see all 5 buttons.

I don't know exactly why it does it like that, but it has to do with the initialization of the controls. The result could also have been that it added 3 buttons to the vbox and none to the hbox. But because the hbox is initialized after the vbox, is why it puts button 2 and 3 in the vbox and discards them in the hbox.( or actually throws an exception)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but Slanec answered more early and "clean"